# Is the first write of default values forcefully flushed to main memory in Java?

Tags: java, jvm

I heard from somewhere that

> The first write to shared primitive variables' default values are immediately visible to other threads

I guess it wants to say that the first write to default values are flushed to memory instead of being cached in local memory.

Like

```java
static boolean flag;
// thread 1
flag = true; // and flushed it to main memory
// thread 2
read(flag); // and flag==true is immediately visible to thread 2 if it fetches it from memory using getstatic after flag = true is executed by thread 1
```

But I was not able to find any resources verifying it. Nor could I make a experiment to reproduce it.(I don't know how to inspect main memory values).

So does anyone with relevant knowledge verify it to be true or false?

Comment: You'd have to quote the original source, but it's likely referring to a [class' initialization procedure](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se19/html/jls-12.html#jls-12.4.2) and the default values of static fields (ie. `false` for a `boolean`). This all happens while holding a lock so is later visible to other threads.

Comment: Without any specific knowledge, I'd say that sounds like the kind of thing that may be true-ish for common implementations but isn't required by the spec. I'm not aware of anything in the spec requiring something like that (but then again I'm not an expert on the Java memory model).

Comment: Ask yourself this: how would it detect that the write is the first one or not? It would likely require an extra check for each write, which would just add overhead. It's pretty unlikely that the first write is treated any differently than subsequent ones.

Comment: “flush to main memory” is an entirely wrong mindset. There is no “flush” and in fact, an implementation doesn’t even have to have a “main memory”. As Sotirios Delimanolis said, the default value is the “`false`” that the field has before the write of a non-default value. What is guaranteed, is that a thread can’t perceive a value that was in this memory location before this initialization. Which doesn’t require a flush but just a mechanism to prevent reading the variable before the initialization.